# Instructions to mount an internal hard drive?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gparted, fdisk

How do you mount an internal hard drive?  I have a 500GB internal hard drive that has both linux and windows 7.  Upon booting up I decide which one to use.  My windows 7 OS has a user, which requires me to enter a password for upon logging in.

How would I mount an internal hard drive to access the files stored in that user's account (I have the user's password)?

Also, can you please give me instructions using fdisk instead of gparted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows partition should be visible in the left panel of Ubuntu file browser. Clicking on it should mount the drive and show you the files.

If you prefer to mount the partition from command line, something like this would work:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/your-partition-device /some/folder/to/serve/as/mountpoint
```

It's not clear why you're asking about fdisk and gparted - you definitely don't need those to access your files.